# WhatsApp - writing a clone (iphone, android, wp7)

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, udp, instant-messaging

I am trying to create a instant messaging app very much like whatsapp I suppose. My resources I have available to me are Server development in C# (REST Service, dedicated server app etc)

And currently an android development platform using eclipse (iphone, wp7 to follow later). I have done some development in Android before but I don't have any idea where to start an application like this.

My guess would be it would work with UDP / TCP or similar ? I currently have a shared server for an asp.net website but I presume this wouldn't be ideal, I could essential setup a web service on the server and get a client to publish his messages there but then this would mean that the receivers would have to POLL (PULL) every 5 minutes or so - so I guess this wouldn't be real time

Do I need to use UDP here ?

And I presume platforms like Iphone, Android and WP7 will not have any issues sending msgs by UDP - if that is how its done.

I look forward to any help or guidance.

Comment: Do you want to write an app that can inter operate with WhatsApp clients? If not, why don't you use the xmpp protocol? Try asmack for a start then.

Comment: I agree with Dirk. Rather than try to reinvent the IM wheel, pick a protocol and server stack for that, with XMPP being the likely candidate.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. No i am not trying to interoperate with whatsapp... The xmpp looks great but the problem being is that works via tcp - doesn't it? and it appears that each language needs an api library. I thought the idea was to use UDP. Also it appears i would have to create a XMPP server and the components for these don't seem to be free for c#

Comment: Does XMPP work similar to UDP then? i.e. not like TCP where it requires actually connections

Comment: Ok after a little investigation, yep seems that XMPP is the way to go... Anyone care to post it as an answer so i can accept the reply..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As all the other comments already suggested you should go with XMPP - there is a huge collection of available libraries you can find [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Best wishes,
Tim